# Convert FormCollection && HttpRequest to Hashtable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two function that one receives a `FormCollection` and another receives a `HttpRequest` like this:

```
public void SetUrlParameters(FormCollection request, string controllerName = "")
{
    string sessionID = ConvertToString(request["sessionID"]);
    string idSession = ConvertToString(request["idSession"]);
    string sessionid = ConvertToString(request["sessionid"]);

    if (idSession.Length > 0)
        this.sessionID = idSession;
    else if (sessionid.Length > 0)
        this.sessionID = sessionid;
    else
        this.sessionID = sessionID;

}

private void SetUrlParameters(HttpRequest request, string controllerName = "")
{

    string sessionID = ConvertToString(request["sessionID"]);
    string idSession = ConvertToString(request["idSession"]);
    string sessionid = ConvertToString(request["sessionid"]);

    if (idSession.Length > 0)
        this.sessionID = idSession;
    else if (sessionid.Length > 0)
        this.sessionID = sessionid;
    else
        this.sessionID = sessionID;

}

private string ConvertToString(object obj, string defaultValue = "")
{
      if (obj == null) return defaultValue;

      return Convert.ToString(filterSameVariablesValue(obj));
}
```

As you can see, the both the functions do exact the same. The only difference is the type of the value that each one receives.

Both function are working. What I want is to avoid having repeated code in both function.

There is any way that I can collapse this to function into one ? Like for example convert the `FormCollection` and `HttpRequest` to a `Hashtable` and the use it?

Comment: what have you tried? what has not worked?

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama Both function are working.What I want is to avoid having repeated code in both function.

Comment: I don't think you should be using the `HttpRequest` indexer at all. It accesses the query string, form, cookies *and* server variables at once, which is something you shouldn't ever need to do.

Comment: I understood that, but you still need to give an indication of how you've tried to do that and what has not worked...

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I'm not sure what else you think OP could provide here...

Comment: @DavidG only going by what is prescribed in the help section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply expect a `NameValueCollection` parameter that is a (almost) common to both types:

```
private void SetUrlParameters(NameValueCollection data, string controllerName = "")
{
    string sessionID = ConvertToString(data["sessionID"]);
    string idSession = ConvertToString(data["idSession"]);
    string sessionid = ConvertToString(data["sessionid"]);

    if (idSession.Length > 0)
        this.sessionID = idSession;
    else if (sessionid.Length > 0)
        this.sessionID = sessionid;
    else
        this.sessionID = sessionID;
}
```

Usage for `HttpRequest`:

```
SetUrlParameters(request.Params);
```

Usage for `FormCollection`:

```
SetUrlParameters(formCollection);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[FormCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) is inherits from `NameValueCollection`. `HttpRequest` has `HttpRequest.Form` property which is `NameValueCollection` too. So your can avoid duplication using convertion to `NameValueCollection`

```
public void GetParameters(FormCollection form, HttpRequest request)
{
    var parameters = Convert(form);
    parameters = Convert(request.Parameters);
}

public YourParameters Convert(NameValueCollection form)
{
    //your code here
}
```